# Create a variable containing the text: ```\`\`\`test\`\`\````

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to create a Javascript variable containing exactly this string.

[image]

That sequence is (with spaces so Stack Overflow doesn't reformat it for me):

`` ` ` ` ` \ ` \ ` t e s t \ ` \ ` \ ` ` ` ``

However, watch what happens when I try to create that string in console:
[image]

How do I create exactly that string in console?

Comment: You did. The node console will escape things as needed

Comment: You double up backslashes like the duplicate says... The duplicate does answer your question.